# Unexpected token "(" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, token

I've checked all of my parentheses and it looks okay to me, what's the deal? (I'm doing the Javascript course at Codecademy) [random text here because stackoverflow wants me to have a better ratio between text and code]

```
function StaffMember(name,discountPercent){
    this.name = name;
    this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
}

var sally = new StaffMember("Sally",5);
var bob = new StaffMember("Bob",10);

// Create yourself again as 'me' with a staff discount of 20%
var me = new StaffMember("Axel", 20);

var cashRegister = {
    total:0,
    lastTransactionAmount: 0,
    add: function(itemCost){
        this.total += (itemCost || 0);
        this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
    },
    scan: function(item,quantity){
        switch (item){
        case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
        case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
        case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
        case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
        }
        return true;
    },
    voidLastTransaction : function(){
        this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
        this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
    },
    // Create a new method applyStaffDiscount here
    applyStaffDiscount(employee){
        this.total -= (this.total * (employee.discountpercent/100));
    }

};

cashRegister.scan('eggs',1);
cashRegister.scan('milk',1);
cashRegister.scan('magazine',3);
// Apply your staff discount by passing the 'me' object 
// to applyStaffDiscount
cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(me);

// Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: *[random text here because stackoverflow wants me to have a better ratio between text and code]*. Yup, and there is a reason for that.

Comment: I'm sure you're provided with a line number of the error, yes?

Comment: No? What browser are you using? Firefox/Firebug not only shows the line, but provides a nice little arrow pointing exactly where your error is (confirmed using jsfiddle). Safari also shows the line number, although isn't as specific about where in the line the error is.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not okay, you have syntax errors in your literal where you're creating the `applyStaffDiscount` property

```
voidLastTransaction : function(){
    this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
    this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
},
applyStaffDiscount(employee){
    this.total -= (this.total * (employee.discountpercent/100));
}
```

Let's assume you where really trying to create a function, as you're trying to pass arguments and have parenthesis etc

```
voidLastTransaction : function(){
    this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
    this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
},
applyStaffDiscount : function(employee){
    this.total -= (this.total * (employee.discountpercent/100));
}
```